# Should I tag the question with a similar tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, I have a question about C++11.

Then, should I also tag the question with a `c++` tag? Are there any guidelines on this kind of situations?

Also, if I don't mention the `c++` tag, will my question's title be prefixed with `c++11 - etc.`?